# Xamarin studio - ignore package updates?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have a Xamarin iOS project that used to, but no longer compiles.

The same code, same component and nuget package references no longer compiles.

The error messages are like:
`The type or namespace 'xamarin' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

(Yes, it cannot find Xamarin. I've also had this with Google.Maps and Newtonsoft.Json).

Xamarin studio shows packages with updates available. If I choose to update the package, the build progresses a bit further (or complains about a different missing library).

I don't want to update the packages. The ones we are using are stable for our use and known good.

How do I tell Xamarin Studio that I don't want to update, and in fact, I'd like to continue to use the version that's known to work?

Thanks

Comment: If you do a Nuget "Restore" (Via a Solution Level `Nuget Restore Packages`), are you receiving any errors in the "Package Console" window?

Comment: With Nuget Restore, I get "Packages successfully restored." up the top, and the Package Console says "Restoring packages... Skipping x because it is lready restored (repeated), All packages are already restored."

Comment: Assuming your original soluton's projects has all the proper references in the each project's `packages.config` that is all you should have to do to as Xamarin Studio will not "upgrade" to newer Nuget  packages unless you tell it to.

Comment: Cheap shot but have you tried deleting the obj and bin folder in the solution? When I start to get Xamarin missing errors usually something with the temp files has gone sideways...

Answer (score 0):

> How do I tell Xamarin Studio that I don't want to update, and in fact, I'd like to continue to use the version that's known to work?

The simplest approach is to do nothing. Xamarin Studio will not automatically update your NuGet packages. You need to trigger the update yourself.

You can also disable the checking for NuGet package updates in Preferences - NuGet - General.

[image: NuGet package check for updates]

Finally if you want to make sure that the NuGet packages are not updated then you can put restriction in the packages.config file:

```
<packages>
    <package id="SomePackage" version="2.1.0" allowedVersions="[2,3)" />
</packages>
```

There is more information on the supported allowedVersions syntax on the [NuGet site](https://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning)

However all the above will not fix your build errors if you are getting an error without modifying the NuGet packages.